# Use of snowball stemmer in Perl

Tags: perl

please I am trying to stem a content of a file using the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Lingua::Stem::Snowball;

my $filename = 'input.txt';
open my $info, $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $line = <$info>)

    {
    my $sent;
    chomp $line;
    my @words = qw($line);
    my $stemmer = Lingua::Stem::Snowball->new( lang => 'en' );
    $stemmer->stem_in_place( \@words );
    open FILE, ">>output.txt" or die $!;
    print FILE "stem_in_place\n"; 
    close FILE;
    }
```

This gives me the error:

> "Can't locate loadable object for module Lingua::Stem::Snowball in
>   @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at
>   snowballTry.pl line 4.  Compilation failed in require at
>   snowballTry.pl line 4. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   snowballTry.pl line 4."

Please what do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to install missing modules used, give a try to :

```
cpan Lingua::Stem::Snowball
```

Install `Lingua::Stem::Snowball` module with [cpan](http://www.cpan.org) and the error will magically disappear ...

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I have installed this but the error still comes up

Comment: @EbukaI Read [toolic's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155267/use-of-snowball-stemmer-in-perl#comment44683331_28155267) on your question. `Can't locate loadable object for module Foo` means that `Foo` is trying to load an external shared library like `foo.so` but can't find it. Are you sure you didn't get any errors when installing `Lingua::Stem::Snowball`?